# Julia from Mac terminal vs Julia Studio

Tags: macos, julia, julia-studio

I'm trying to run some basic Julia scripts (loading data and manipulating it) from the command line (using a MAC terminal) that I had previously written and successfully compiled with Julia Studio. I KNOW they work (I have re-run them countless times in Julia Studio) and see the desired output sans error messages, but for some reason I now keep getting strange errors some of which seem to relate to packages such as `DataFrames` (but not always of that variety) when I run the aforementioned scripts from the command line?

```
ERROR: no method readtable(Array{Any,1},)
ERROR: no method date_parser(ASCIIString,)
```

If anyone has encountered a similar problem then I would love to hear about the fix.

Comment: Which version of Julia do you have installed?

Comment: I am using version 0.2.0 mac.

Comment: This smell version compatibility errors. Compare `versioninfo(true)` in both environments.

Comment: when I run that command what specifically am I looking for between the Julia and Julia Studio?

Comment: ERROR: in module path: Dataframes not defined
 in include at boot.jl:238
 in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:119
 in process_options at client.jl:307
 in _start at client.jl:387
at /Users/MacBookPro15/dataf.jl:2

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the Julia version. This problem was there in previous versions. Also try iJulia, you will find it better than terminal.

Comment: Kindly Add some more Content